# How do I make a color picker default to a CSS variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, color-picker

I am coding a color picker. I am trying to figure out how to make it default to a CSS variable, and then have it change the CSS variable in question. The variable is called `--bg` and is for changing the background color.

I tried using `value="var(--bg)"` but that didn't work. I then tried this JavaScript code generated by ChatGPT:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const colorPicker = document.getElementById('bgcolor');
    colorPicker.value = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--bg').trim();

    colorPicker.addEventListener('input', function() {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--bg', this.value);
    });
});
```

Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the bg color without using a variable:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const colorPicker = document.getElementById('bgcolor');

    colorPicker.oninput = function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = colorPicker.value;
    };
});
```

I have modified an other thing, this is not "colorPicker.input" but "colorPicker.oninput".

Then I just setting the background color with the value of the color picker.